# Stack operations using list

Tags: c, stack

I'm trying to program a Stack on C using linked list. I have a problem with CreateStack function. Everything seems fine when I create one stack but when I try to create another, the program just crashes. Here is the part of my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct StackData{
    int data;
    struct StackData* prev;
    struct StackPoint* point;
};

struct StackPoint{
    struct StackData* basePointer;
    struct StackData* stackPointer;
    char exists;
};

int CreateNewStack(struct StackData** newPointer){
    if((*newPointer)->point->exists=='Y') //i'm trying to check whether the list with the same adress has been already created and i think this is the part which causes error
        return 1; //if error
    else{
        (*newPointer)=(struct StackData*)malloc(sizeof(struct StackData));
        (*newPointer)->data=NULL;
        (*newPointer)->prev=NULL;
        (*newPointer)->point=(struct StackPoint*)malloc(sizeof(struct StackPoint));
        (*newPointer)->point->basePointer=newPointer;
        (*newPointer)->point->stackPointer=newPointer;
        (*newPointer)->point->exists='Y';
        return 0;
    }
}

int main()
{
    struct StackData *pointeris, *temp;
    int state;
    state=CreateNewStack(&pointeris);  //state 0

    state=CreateNewStack(&pointeris);  //state 1


    CreateNewStack(&temp);            //crash
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And what debugging have you done on your own? Suggest you run your program in a debugger and/or add more debugging print statements to help you find the problem. That's just debugging 101.

Comment: Use of the value of an object with automatic storage duration before it is initialized is undefined behavior.

Comment: This code has a number of compiler warnings.  Turn on `-Wall`, recompile, and fix them.  Then see if your problem goes away or repost the fixed code.

Comment: `(*newPointer)->point->exists=='Y'` apart from being a weired way to check for a pointer it's also completely wrong as the passed in `*newPointer` is uninitialised the first time `CreateNewStack` is called and hence contains garbage. Dereferencing an unintialised pointer is Undefined Behaviour and all bets are off from that point forward.

Comment: `int CreateNewStack` - don't use a `**` argument, but just return the new stack, a _null pointer_ for error. And don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code has compiler warnings.

```
test.c:21:28: warning: incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'int' from 'void *'
      [-Wint-conversion]
        (*newPointer)->data=NULL;
                           ^~~~~
test.c:24:42: warning: incompatible pointer types assigning to 'struct StackData *' from
      'struct StackData **'; dereference with * [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
        (*newPointer)->point->basePointer=newPointer;
                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~
                                          *
test.c:25:43: warning: incompatible pointer types assigning to 'struct StackData *' from
      'struct StackData **'; dereference with * [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
        (*newPointer)->point->stackPointer=newPointer;
                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~
                                           *
```

After fixing those the immediate problem is this line:

```
if((*newPointer)->point->exists=='Y')
```

`*newPointer` might be null.  `*newPointer->point` might be garbage.  `*newPointer->point->exists` might be garbage.

Part of the problem is `CreateNewStack` is really "maybe create a new stack if the stack doesn't already exist".  Your code will be much simpler if you separate "create a new stack" from "create a new stack if it doesn't already exist".  In fact, every struct should have its own creation and destruction function.

I've also taken the liberty of adding typedefs for your structs.  And I've switched from `malloc` to `calloc` to ensure the allocated structs are zero'd on creation.  This means there will never be any garbage in a struct's members even if you forget to initialize every member.

```
typedef struct StackData {
    int data;
    struct StackData* prev;
    struct StackPoint* point;
} StackData;

typedef struct StackPoint {
    struct StackData* basePointer;
    struct StackData* stackPointer;
    char exists;
} StackPoint;

StackPoint *CreateStackPoint() {
    StackPoint *point = calloc(1, sizeof(StackPoint));

    point->exists = 'Y';

    return point;
}

StackData *CreateStackData() {
    StackData *data = calloc(1, sizeof(StackData));

    data->point = CreateStackPoint();
    data->point->basePointer  = data;
    data->point->stackPointer = data;

    return data;
}
```

Now `CreateNewStack` becomes `MaybeCreateStackData` and is much simpler.

```
int MaybeCreateStackData(StackData **maybeStack_p) {
    if( maybeStack_p == NULL ) {
        fprintf(stderr, "The stack double pointer cannot be null");
        exit(1);
    }

    StackData *maybeStack = *maybeStack_p;

    if( maybeStack && maybeStack->point && maybeStack->point->exists == 'Y' ) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        *maybeStack_p = CreateStackData();
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Quite honestly the scheme is over-complicated.  In C, it's difficult to know when a pointer has been properly initialized vs just pointing at random memory.  Your `exists` member tries to work around that, but garbage could still turn up `Y`.

Instead, I'd drop the whole idea and let the caller decide if they have a valid struct or not.  Now that you have solid initializer functions, it's much less likely someone will have a badly initialized pointer.